# Javascript, array of "this" and more about arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have seen a piece of code that I can't figure out:

```
for (var m in client.actorTypes[d[5]]) {
   if (m !== 'update' && m !== 'destroy' && m !== 'remove') {
      this[m] = client.actorTypes[d[5]][m];
   }
}
```

but actorTypes is not a 2D array:

```
Game.prototype.BaseActor = function(rate) {
   this.updateRate   = rate;
   this.onCreate     = function(data, complete) {};
   this.onUpdate     = function(data) {};
   this.onEvent      = function(data) {};
   this.onInterleave = function() {};
   this.onDraw       = function() {};
   this.onDestroy    = function(complete) {};
};

Game.prototype.Actor = function(id, rate) {
   return this.$.actorTypes[id] = new this.BaseActor(rate);
};
```

I actually don't know what happens in this code. Can someone explain it to me? What is a `this` array, and how could `actorTypes` become a 2d array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays have nothing to do with it.

In Javascript, you can access object properties in one of two ways:

1. `theObject.theProperty`
2. `theObject['theProperty']`

Method *1* is only possible with a literal, valid variable name; method *2* allows you to use an arbitrary expression (e.g. in your case, a string variable).

Arrays are a special case of Javascript objects, which happen to have numerically-named properties. We use method *2* to access them because valid variable names may not start with (or be solely) numbers.

That doesn't mean that every time you see `x[y]`, `x` must be an array, because that's not the case at all.

A clarifying example follows:

```
var o = {
   'a': {
      'b': 5
   }
};

var x = 'a', y = 'b';

console.log(o.a.b);       // Output: 5
console.log(o['a']['b']); // Output: 5
console.log(o[x][y]);     // Output: 5
```

All of those three are equivalent, and `o` is still not an array.

Comment: aah so actually this[m]=xx means this.m=xx as actortypes[id][m]=xx means actortypes[id].m=xx ? am i right?

Comment: @deniz: Almost. `this.m` is the same as `this['m']`, but instead you're getting `this[m]` which is the property whose name is the same as the _contents of the variable `m`_, not actually `'m'`. There's an extra level of indirection.

Comment: for ex m = "asd", so i actually define this["asd"] (this."asd") = xx ?

Comment: @deniz: Essentially, yes. Except that `this."asd"` is not valid syntax, which is why `this["asd"]` exists instead.

Comment: Thanks. How does "for in" work for classes(i mean functions) ? Does it get ALL of the elements including functions ?

Comment: @deniz: [Yep (though browsers sometimes apply special filters to "type"s that they recognise, such as `Array`)](http://kera.name/articles/2011/09/a-brief-introduction-to-javascript-objects-arrays/)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and objects in Javascript are very similar. You can use `for( var i in object )` to loop through members of an object, like you would loop through an array with `for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )`. Similarly, you can use array access on an object: `object.property` is the same as `object['property']`.

Comment: Actually, arrays are rather just objects with numeric property names.

Comment: actually i have no problem about "for..in", i couldnt get this array and usage of actortypes

Comment: `You can use for( var i in object ) to loop through members of an object as if they were an array.` Except you should _never_ loop through a Javascript `Array` in such a manner.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, you shouldn't. I didn't mean to imply that you should loop through arrays in that manner, just that you can loop through objects this way.

Comment: @RyanP: The "as if they were an array" suggests otherwise, but ok glad to hear it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I changed that for you.

Answer (score 0):

BaseActor and Actor are the methods attached to the Game object. The **this** inside Actor nothing but the reference to the object instance.
So whenever a Game object will be instantiated, it will have these BaseActor and Actor methods attached to it. For e.g

```
var obj = new Game();
```

the `return this.$.actorTypes[id] = new this.BaseActor(rate);` inside the Actor will set the value of 'id' inside the actorTypes array object to the BaseActor object instance hence consisting of all the properties of that class.